# Scalebar doesn't match up with actual dimensions

Tags: qgis, units, scale-bar

Every time I make a map, the scalebar doesn't match with what the real dimensions of my map should be. I've been doing maps of Chicago in CRS: NAD83 and every time I put the map in the print composer and add the map and scalebar, it says that Chicago is .04m... Which is obviously not correct in the slightest. Also, I am unable to change the units in my map.

[image]

Comment: Coordinate systems having units in longitude/latitude degrees are not scalebar-friendly.  Consider using some projected coordinate system.